# How can I programmatically determine if a Jena parser is registered that can handle a format?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, apache-jena

I'm writing a DCAT query component and ideally I'd be able to load a Jena model with as many distributions are available in the catalog (assuming they're not different representations of the same data, which according to my experience they usually aren't).

But if I arbitrarily try to load any accessURL or downloadURL found in the DCAT document, an exception is thrown in Jena because the data isn't the intended format of the parser (Jena guesses based on MIME types and file extensions).

I know that new parser objects can be registered with the RDFParserRegistry, which I assume is referenced during Model.read(), but I'd like to only attempt Model.read( ) if I know that a parser is registered for reading the kind of document I'm going to retrieve.  But I don't see a way of doing that using RDFParserRegistry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially you have some URI e.g. `http://example.org/foo` found in some data  that you want to attempt to load further data about as RDF but you don't know if the URI provides data in a format that Jena supports?

In order to find out what format the data is available in you would need to make a HTTP `GET` request to the URI manually passing a RDF centric `Accept` header (`WebContent.defaultGraphAcceptHeader` provides the header Jena will use for requests).  You can then examine the `Content-Type` returned by the remote server.

Once you have this you can use this to check for a parser like so:

```
Lang lang = RDFLanguages.contentTypeToLang(contentType);
if (lang != null) {
  // Language is known, is there an RDF parser for it?
  ReaderRIOTFactory parserFactory = RDFParserRegistry.getFactory(lang);
  if (parserFactory != null) {
    // Parser registered
    // Read your model
  }
}
```

Note that you may want to read the model directly from the `InputStream` from your `GET` request as if you just do a `model.read()` with the URI you'll force Jena to download the content again.

Since this approach requires you to make a HTTP request to the remote resource anyway it may actually be more efficient to just try a `model.read()` regardless and `catch` and log/ignore the errors that occur.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes I was looking to not have to do the http request manually first since that's what Jena does anyway.  I guess I'll should just catch the exception and move on if it fails.

Comment: Either you edited your answer or I was still half asleep when I read it :).  So if there has been an entry made  for the language type, RDFLanguages.contentTypeToLang shall return that registered language.  Then I'll need to check whether or not the associated parser factory had been associated with the language, as the lang may be registered but not the factory.  In addition, I could probably just do an http HEAD on the URL with Jena accept header to improve performance when asking for the content type to check.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for a language to exist but to not have an appropriate parser